# Wifi speed dropping for HP Pavilion 15-n097sa

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04, realtek

I recently moved to Ubuntu 14.04 from Windows 8.1. I have quite a problem with my WiFi speed dropping. When I checked it at speedtest.net it went from 30Mbps to less than 1Mbps then goes up again to about 18Mbps in just a few seconds. That's happening all the time making video calls impossible as well as streaming music and watching videos on YouTube. The problem is not existent in when running Windows. I have a "Integrated 10/100 BASE-T Ethernet LAN" with just the stock driver on a HP Pavilion 15. The power management of wlan0 is off. I have almost no knowledge of the terminal so if you help me please explain it like I'm a complete noob (which is true). Cheers!

- [specs of my laptop](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&docname=c03987135)
- `lspci -vnn | grep Network`:

  ```
  08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)
  ```

Comment: The Broadcom driver for that model could be the BCM4331 or the BCM4312, both of which are in the marked duplicate question in the Broadcom list.

Comment: But when I ran the command  "lspci -vnn | grep Network" it gave me the following line:
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)

Should I still look at the broadcom drivers?

Comment: Then your case is not Broadcom but Realtek (The BCM4313 with pci:id  10ec:8179)

Comment: Please, please dear sir. Tell me which of the answers should I follow. I tried the first. It made it worse. I feel completely lost now.

Comment: I have written to your email to do a follow up on your problem.

Comment: just in case someone has the same problem I solved it by updating the kernel to v3.14.1

Comment: Yes, 3.14.x fixes many network issues. It fixed a couple of Wireless issues I was having with newer motherboards (Like Asus and MSI) and it also fixed on the same models Bluetooth issues. I don't know if this will be backported to 3.13 but I know that 14.10 will have all this issues fixed.

Comment: Could you please convert your twice upvoted comment to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more?  **;-)**  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)
Oh, and, please, don't put "solved" in the title, just accept your own answer in a few days by ticking the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to OP's comment:

> I solved it by updating the kernel to v3.14.1.